Are heater controls universal?
Im looking to switch my mecanical heater controls for wifi enabled ones.
Thing is, behind the control theres only 2 cables.

I have the feeling that the one with all the bells and whisles would need more current than the mecanical ones, so thats why im checking; do any heater control you can get is fine with only those two wires? Or if i take the big wifi enabled ones would i need to have to call an electrician for an extra wire?
If there are some that would need that extra current, what attribute should i look for?
Also this is for online ordering so yeah i cant simply go to the shop and look

A picture showing the wires inside the box will help.  Wifi/smart controls do not use much power, but usually do require neutral, which is probably in that box.  You will need a control that can pass the current and volts required for the heater.

theres only 2 cables. ... it is one cable containing multiple wires

That old mechanical thermostat controls the heat by shorting the two wires when it asks for heat and opening the contact when it's warm enough. The actual actuation of the switching is powered by the differential expansion and contraction of a bimetalic strip in response to temperature changes.
Given that I see the thermostat wires connected to black wires through wire nuts one of which has 3 wires in it and I see a white neutral in there I suspect it's directly controlling an 120 or 240V electrical heater. You can check that with a multimeter.
This alone means that you need a thermostat capable of switching line voltage. Quite a few smart thermostats only deal with 24V switching.
And if I'm right about the white wire then you should have the power available to run it right there in the box.

An industry term for this is "line voltage thermostat."

Search for "line voltage smart thermostat" and you'll find many options.
